# Loading drive images in GridView, Android

Tags: android, gridview

Hye all, i'm new to android. I wanted to ask is it possible to add your drive folder images in gridView? So far i've done the application where i'm manually adding the images in drawable folder. But now i want to load the online images.Plus i don't want to add the URL of each single image. Can i just add the folder path and let it automatically load the gridView with its images? Below is my ImageAdapter class where i'm manually adding images.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
Bitmap bmImg;
ImageView imageView;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
R.drawable.macro,
        R.drawable.macro1,
        R.drawable.macro2,
        R.drawable.macro3,
        R.drawable.macro4,
        R.drawable.macro5,
        R.drawable.macro6,
        R.drawable.macro7,


};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
    return imageView;
}
```